# Visual Studio Code launch.json settings for debugging Python modules

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Currently I have my file structure like this:

```
├── Utilities
|   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── module1.py
├── main.py
├── global_var.py
```

In `main.py` and `module1.py` I have already written `import global_var`, and everything goes well when I run `main.py`.

However, when I tried to debug or run `module1.py` itself, it always shows

> Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError 
> No module named 'global_var'

And I have to manually move `module1.py` to the same folder with `global_var.py` so that it can run successfully.

I would like to know how to set the `launch.json` to stop moving the files. Here's my `launch.json` right now:

```
{
    "name": "Python: Modules",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${file}",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "console": "integratedTerminal"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what the name of the parent folder of file '`global_var.py`' is, so I temporarily named it `folder_aa`.

Since they are not in the same folder, Visual Studio Code cannot find the path, so you could tell it the path of the file you want to import:

1. Add the line of settings to the `launch.json` file of `.vscode` file:

   > `"env": {"PYTHONPATH" : "${workspaceRoot}"},`

   Visual Studio Code will find the root directory (the project folder name) of the current project according to `"${workspaceRoot}"`.
2. Use '`from folder_aa import global_var`' instead of '`import global_var`'.

   Visual Studio Code will find file 'global_var.py' from folder 'folder_aa'.

I created a project similar to the directory structure you provided, and through the above operations, it can be successfully imported.

My environment: Python 3.8.3; Visual Studio Code 1.47.3; OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18362

Comment: ya it does work. However I found that I will have to modify A LOT to fit this solution, and pycharm can easily solve this by setting root directory. I would hold for a while until I'm tired of pycharm lol